# Please explain the following code containing Partition and Flatten

Tags: syntax, partitions

I'm a beginner in *Mathematica*. I have the following code:

```
A = NestList[func, x0, n];
B = Partition[Flatten[{#, #, #, #} & /@ A][[2 ;; -2]], 2]
```

I don't understand the meaning of the syntax for `B`. What exactly is happening there (could someone explain this in words?). How could one understand the interval directly after the `Flatten` function and what is it addressing?

Comment: What about evaluating this step by step? `{#, #, #, #} & /@ A` then `Flatten[%]` etc?

Comment: This is a Great tip. Tried it out and now i‘m wondering why i didn‘t do this in the first place ✌️

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at it from the inside out, starting with

```
{#,#,#,#} &
```

This is a nameless function which takes any input and returns a list containing that input 4 times by directly repeating its argument.

```
{#,#,#,#} & /@ A
```

This `Map`s (`/@` is a shorthand infix for `Map`) the nameless function over every member of `A`. This returns a list containing lists of 4 copies for every member of `A`.

```
Flatten[{#,#,#,#} & /@ A]
```

This flattens that list of lists back into a normal list, effectively creating a 1D list repeating each element of `A` 4 times in the same order that `A` has them.

```
Flatten[{#,#,#,#} & /@ A][[2 ;; -2]]
```

This then takes the second through second to last members of that list, discarding the very first and the very last elements.

```
Partition[Flatten[{#,#,#,#} & /@ A][[2 ;; -2]], 2]
```

Finally this breaks the list into non-overlapping pairs, starting from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear explanation. In the Future i will try to decompose new confusing code similarly.